# compass app unable to instantiate activity

Tags: java, android, view

I am trying to make an compass-based app.I have two java files, one is the `Compass` class and it extends `View`, and the 2nd one is the `Sensors` class. In the xml file relatated to the latter class, there is an `<View>` item and it is as shown below. The problem is when I run the app, it crashes and logcat generate the below output. please help me to solve this problem.

XML:

```
     <view 
        android:id="@+id/mycompass" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        class="com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00"/>
```

Instantiation of Compass class:

```
CompassTest00 myCompass;
myCompass = (CompassTest00) findViewById(R.id.mycompass);
```

CompassClass:

```
public class CompassTest00 extends View {

private float direction;

public CompassTest00(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CompassTest00(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }

public CompassTest00(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
      MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));      
}

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      int w = getMeasuredWidth();
      int h = getMeasuredHeight();
      int r;
      if(w > h){
      r = h/2;
       }else{
        r = w/2;
       }
      Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
      paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

      canvas.drawCircle(w/2, h/2, r, paint);

      paint.setColor(Color.RED);
      canvas.drawLine(
        w/2,
        h/2,
        (float)(w/2 + r * Math.sin(-direction)),
        (float)(h/2 - r * Math.cos(-direction)),
        paint);
}

 public void update(float dir){
      direction = dir;
      invalidate();
     }  
}
```

ManifestFile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.compasstest00"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.compasstest00.AndroidSensors"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_android_sensors" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

LogcatOutput:

```
04-22 02:50:06.817: D/dalvikvm(8545): newInstance failed: no <init>()
04-22 02:50:06.817: D/AndroidRuntime(8545): Shutting down VM
04-22 02:50:06.817: W/dalvikvm(8545): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught  
exception (group=0x419a1700)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  
instantiate activity   
ComponentInfo{com.example.compasstest00/com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00}:   
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class   
com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00; no empty constructor
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2232)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at   
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at   
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545): Caused by:   
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class    
com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00; no empty constructor
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at  
java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at  
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at    
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2223)
04-22 02:50:06.817: E/AndroidRuntime(8545):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have you tried `<com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00>` instead of `<view class="com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00">`?

Comment: I think we need to see the `CompassTest00` class.

Comment: where should i place the layout_width and other items then?could you please explain more?

Comment: should I post the compass class?

Comment: Yes, you should post the compass class, and for the view, you would write it `<com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00 android:id="@+id/mycompass" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />` Just the way it already is, just without the `class=`

Comment: Actually, I think the XML file might be fine the way you had it.

Comment: I tried your way but i got the same error. should i add a permission to te manifest file or something?

Comment: I posted the compass class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00 
    android:id="@+id/mycompass" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Instead of:

```
<view 
    android:id="@+id/mycompass" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    class="com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00"/>
```

**Update:**

In fact both ways of declaring custom views in XML should work. The actual problem is in the Android Manifest:

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00"
```

==> You declared your custom view as an activity. That is why `ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity` failed to instantiate it. (because it shouldn't!)

==> You should declare an activity class in your android manifest instead. This activity can then set the customview as its contentView.

Comment: when i'm tring ur answer, pressing ctrl+space"auto complete" does not show my class name as if it is not recognisable

Comment: In my project ctrl+space suggests the class name in xml. Not sure why it is not doing so for yours. However try this code and save the xml. Also clean project before running app.

Comment: in mine, it recognizses it when i use <View.... but when I use <com.example......... it does not

Comment: should i write somthing in the constructor?

Comment: In theory no other constructor should be added, because the missing empty constructor that the logcat is complaining about is not applicable for view class and it should work without...

Comment: I have another suspect. Can I take a look at your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Ok, I see: `<activity
        android:name="com.example.compasstest00.CompassTest00"` seems like you declared your custom view as an activity. That seems like is the problem.

Comment: despite that your updated answer is correct, i got another problem in the logcat i would create a new question. thank you